# Magento connect manager cannot opened

Tags: magento

Hi All I've got this page when try to open magento connect manager from my magento.

Permission set to 777.

Have any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to install any extensions,  you can paste the extension key [here](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. than you can install the extension through ftp [ like filezilla]

let me know if you find any problems in this.